# Set cursor position on selected file C++ Win API

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

How to set mouse cursor position on selected file in C++ WIN API.

I want to move the mouse cursor on selected file, how to do that?

The cursor have some cool visual effect. I want to make nice thing

I know in WIN API is a function SetCursorPos(pt.x , pt.y); , but is there a solution to get selected file position and just set cursor position to the same position as selected file

Comment: I would leave the mouse cursor alone - that belongs to the user.

Comment: The cursor have some cool visual effect. I want to make nice thing.

Comment: ok, but I'm just saying that if I installed an app that took control of my mouse, I'd pretty soon uninstall it. At least make this "feature" optional so people can disable it.

Comment: Is this an online training type of program? If you want to use Explorer as a subroutine, you should use an Explorer Browser control.